# How many senses Plants/Trees has?

Tags: plants, indriyas

Human has 5 senses. Animal also have 5 I guess. But how many and what senses trees has, as per Hinduism texts?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Plants also have five senses: Touch, Hearing, Vision, Smell, and Taste. Bhrigu stated an observable fact and then an inference based on that observable fact about the senses of plants.

It is mentioned in the following passage from Mahabharata.

> "Bhrigu said, 'Without doubt, though possessed of density, trees have
> space within them. The putting forth of flowers and fruits is always
> taking place in them. They have heat within them in consequence of
> which leaf, bark, fruit, and flower, are seen to droop.
>
> They sicken and dry up. **That shows they have perception of touch.**
>
> Through sound of wind and fire and thunder, their fruits and flowers drop
> down. Sound is perceived through the ear. **Trees have, therefore,
> ears and do hear.**
>
> A creeper winds round a tree and goes about all
> its sides. A blind thing cannot find its way. For this reason **it is
> evident that trees have vision**.
>
> Then again trees recover vigour and
> put forth flowers in consequence of odours, good and bad, of the
> sacred perfume of diverse kinds of dhupas. **It is plain that trees
> have scent.**
>
> They drink water by their roots. They catch diseases of
> diverse kinds. Those diseases again are cured by different operations.
> From this **it is evident that trees have perceptions of taste.**
>
> As one can suck up water through a bent lotus-stalk, trees also, with the
> aid of the wind, drink through their roots. They are susceptible of
> pleasure and pain, and grow when cut or lopped off. **From these
> circumstances I see that trees have life.** They are not inanimate.
>
> [[Section 184, Mokshadharma Parva,  Santi Parva, The Mahabharata]](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m12/m12b011.htm)

Comment: But all these are in reduced state. Of the Pancha Pranas, I think plants don't have the one that causes pain throughout the body (think it's called Vyana).

Comment: @mar yes one of them, that’s why when you kill them it doesn’t hurt and hence sattvic bhojan.