# Does any scripture other than Mahabharata say that plant experiences pain?

Tags: scripture, science, plants

It is mentioned in Mahabharata that [plants also have five senses and also experience pleasure and pain](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/45578/661). I am focusing on pain part only in this question.

> As one can suck up water through a bent lotus-stalk, trees also, with
> the aid of the wind, drink through their roots. **They are susceptible
> of pleasure and pain,** and grow when cut or lopped off. From these
> circumstances I see that trees have life. They are not inanimate.
>
> [[Section 184, Mokshadharma Parva, Santi Parva, The Mahabharata]](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m12/m12b011.htm)

Recent [studies](https://www.biorxiv.org/content/10.1101/507590v4) may also suggest the same.

Do any other scriptures also says that **plant experiences pain**?